# Vagrantfile for phpBB giving error about missing laravel homestead file

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

The [phpBB Vagrant.md document](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/master/phpBB/docs/vagrant.md) doesn't tell you what to do to get started beyond downloading/cloning the Git repo to your local machine, then running `vagrant up` to start the VM. However, I am currently greeted with the following error when attempting to start up the VM.

```
λ vagrant up
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: C:/Users/Phillip/Desktop/phpbb/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- C:/Users/Phillip/Desktop/phpbb/phpBB/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

I am on Windows 10, have Ruby 2.5.1 installed, and Vagrant which all work currently. However, that directory in the project is currently missing. Do I need that file to get this all working, or should I just create my own Vagrantfile using the `INSTALL.html` docs and go that route?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install all of the dependencies with composer.
As written in the readme (https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/tree/master):

> To be able to run an installation from the repo (and not from a pre-built package) you need to run the following commands to install phpBB's dependencies.
>
> cd phpBB
> php ../composer.phar install

If you don't have Composer for Windows, you can just download and install the exe [on the official page](https://getcomposer.org/)

After this you can run vagrant up from the primary folder and it should work.